# using same method for several html tags ids making it react attuning with the id where the @click take place

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

Good day developers. In this app, I'm trying to establish poll votes.  So in my logic I did frame a tag in HTML with several buttons and their respective ids, where the user `@click` might be assigned to a different poll object.

All tags are click-bound to the same method, thus I'm just trying to increase by whichever tag id in order to reuse the same function (its name is `scorer()`).
Let's say this is my tag:

HTML

```
<div id="pollVote">
  <v-btn id="5pts" @click="pollView = false,scorer()" class="mb-3 lime lighten-2" width="40" x-small >5 pts</v-btn>
  <v-btn id="4pts" @click="pollView = false,scorer()" class="mb-3 lime lighten-2" width="40" x-small>4 pts</v-btn>
  <v-btn id="3pts" @click="pollView = false,scorer()" class="mb-3 lime lighten-2" width="40" x-small>3 pts</v-btn>
  <v-btn id="2pts" @click="pollView = false,scorer()" class="mb-3 lime lighten-2" width="40" x-small >2 pts</v-btn>
  <v-btn id="1pts" @click="pollView = false,scorer()" class="mb-3 lime lighten-2" width="40" x-small>1 pts</v-btn>
</div>
```

then the object in my data should return whichever one was clicked. The poll data is the following:

SCRIPT

```
data(){
  return{
    pollComposer: [
      { poll: "5pts", timesVoted: 0.0, pts: 5.0 },
      { poll: "4pts", timesVoted: 0.0, pts: 4.0 },
      { poll: "3pts", timesVoted: 0.0, pts: 3.0 },
      { poll: "2pts", timesvoted: 0.0, pts: 2.0 },
      { poll: "1pts", timesVoted: 0.0, pts: 1.0 }
    ],
  }
}
```

The function should modify the object the user clicked. Basically, I'm just trying to compare the poll value inside the object with the clicked id (`doc.getElementById`, guess it's wrong) through a boolean; then if this state is true the item `timesVoted` would be updated plus 1....but guess this isn't the correct the way to set it cause it doesn't work:

```
METHODS:{
  scorer() {
    this.pollComposer.forEach(iter => {
      if(iter.poll===document.getElementById(iter.poll))  
        return iter.timesVoted=timesVoted+1;
      }
    );
  },
}
```

Any idea about how I could improve this function without precisely creating a new method for each button. Thanks in advance!!! Have good day!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

HTML

```html
<div id="pollVote">
  <v-btn v-for="vote in pollComposer" :id="vote.poll" @click="scorer(vote)">
    {{ vote.pts }} pts
  </v-btn>
</div>
```

Method

```js
scorer(vote) {
  this.pollView = false;
  vote.timesVoted++;
}
```

Comment: Hola dan thanks for your time .It says me vote isn't define

Comment: in your formula i also added an index(vote,index) in order to iterate over all polls in the object

Comment: Is really good and amzingly simple your way , but cant decipher why throws me undefined

Comment: Hi, you're welcome.  It looks like there is a typo in your data #2, it has a lowercase "v":  `timesvoted`.  Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/5e4zkmhL/) you can compare with

Comment: Really thanks Dan ....amazing solution and simplest!!!!...Have a good day!!!